# Which Q&A on Stack Exchange would be the right place to ask questions about suggestions and best practices?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

In my opinion it's a pity that so many interesting suggestion or best practice topics are closed because of "opinion based" like questions.

Is there a way to ask for things like that so that the topic won't get closed? Because of the strict Q&A based form of the sites it is usually quite hard to get an overview of what is possible. Also very often people argument that such questions add no value but they do.

I found a lot of useful information in many closed topics and wanted to write something from me but it is no longer allowed. Some people are looking for possibilities and exact Q&A is in such cases not always possible until you know what you can actually do.

Just look at the view counters of this kind of questions, they are very very popular so wouldn't it be better to allow them? People seem to be interested but those topics sooner or later get closed.

Strictly speaking almost each and every question can be solved in a lot of different ways so all of them are somehow opinion based.

EDIT:

What is by the way the main reason of closing best-practice topics? If I asked these questions:

> (1) What are the best practices for naming unit tests?

or

> (2) What naming conventions for unit tests do you know, use and why did you choose it?

would both topics get closed or only the first one?

EDIT-2

as an answer to [@Paul's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/103081/paul) [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277097/which-qa-on-stack-exchange-would-be-the-right-place-to-ask-questions-about-sugg?noredirect=1#comment118586_277097) - how about this?

> (3) How do/can I organize my unit tests?

Comment: If it's about software development, there is no site where this would really be on-topic.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant software development.

Comment: What about http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour ?

Comment: Best in (1) is a sign of an opinion-related question or poll, which the entire SE network frowns upon. So is (2) do you know/why did you choose .  That might be the primary problem.  If you can rephrase these as factual questions, they might be salvageable.

Comment: I think this best place is with chat.stackoverflow.com depending on the language and if there is enough people in that specific programming language chat room

Comment: @Paul **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: @gnat it is a treasure trove of soft questions.  [they should lead by example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73396)

Comment: @Paul [Are you still confused about what Programmers is for?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5654/31260)

Comment: @t3chb0t Q3 isn't a great start; it cites an abstract problem rather than anything specific: focus the question on the problem that your disorganised tests is creating.

Comment: I think there is a big audience for subjective topics so why not to test another site for this purpose? Some rules had to be established to prevent arguments but it could be really informative especially if people would give reasons why to choose one solution over another and not just saying 'it's cool' etc.

Comment: @t3chb0t ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @gnat Entertained and perplexed.  Yeah, I'm still confused.

Comment: @gnat: to me the "Not Programming Related" site was to general and people felt they can write anything they want. It is indeed very hard to distinguish a 'normal' from a 'discussion' question like this one for example [How do I get started with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) it is not much different from 'How can I organize my unit tests?'

Comment: @t3chb0t you might find [Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260) worth checking