# Where should I go with program architecture best practice questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I asked about a best practice for working with ViewModels in SwiftUI, and:

1. [On Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941407/best-practices-for-viewmodels-for-swiftui-preview), the question was closed as opinion-based, and I was directed to ask at Code Review site.
2. On Code Review I was told that "General "best practices" questions are off-topic here on Code Review" ([link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259094/best-practices-for-viewmodels-for-swiftui-preview?noredirect=1#comment510935_259094)).

Where is the appropriate place to ask about code architecture best practices?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Q&A on Stack Exchange would be the right place to ask questions about suggestions and best practices?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277097/which-qa-on-stack-exchange-would-be-the-right-place-to-ask-questions-about-sugg)

Comment: Related: [Are “Is it a good practice…?” questions off topic or opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296542/11682469)

Comment: @JeanneDark Thank you, I'll try Software Engineering. [This history post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144) also helps me understand why the opinion-based questions seems like a sensitive topic.

Comment: Before you try posting your question in any other site, my advise would be to go through the help center of that site checking particularly the ask/dont-ask sections.

Comment: Do realise *why* opinion based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask total strangers for their opinions, but who can you trust. You can do a test and ask the question on Reddit, see the variety in the responses you will get. IMO searching for best practices is a late game goal, early game you are interested in workable practices that you can comprehend. What you already know is probably good enough, for now.

Comment: Yeah - you have to be careful.  I have had at least two extended 'differences of opinion' with other skilled and experienced developers over design practices.  Of course, I am right and they are wrong, but we had to agree to diagree:)   You only need to mention 'tabs/spaces' and global thermonuclear war breaks out.

Comment: @Gimby and Martin, I am okay with not blindly trusting anybody, I expected to hear about multiple good approaches to widen my perspective, and then I am okay with having to pick one or mix them into another approach.

Comment: [TABs are evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=9m37s) (more context from 05 min 50 secs)